# Telerik ajax RadMap

Tags: javascript, c#, geojson

I am using telerik RadMap with client side binding in the `OnInitialize` client event.
Copied from the examples:

```
    function OnInitialize(sender, args) {
    var originalOptions = args.get_options();
    var geoJSON = document.getElementById("<%= HiddenGeoJSON.ClientID %>").value;
    var data = JSON.parse(geoJSON);
    originalOptions.layers[0].dataSource = { data: data };
    args.set_options(originalOptions);
    }
```

Layer[0] is a shape layer.

when

```
    data = [{"type": "LineString","coordinates": [[35.686274,32.993079],[35.686414,32.993722],[35.686532,32.994366]]}];
```

All is well and the line is drawn.

when

```
    data = [{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"date": "28052015"},"geometry":{ "type":"Point","coordinates":[ 35.686274 , 32.993079 ]}}]}]
```

Nothing happens.